# html dropdown not working in wordpress website

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, dropdown

i have a website in wordpress, th[enter link description here](http://molugu.com/yantraev/)

there is a section in the footer of the websiite like in the below image:

[image]

i want to make this section a dropdown , so i added the following changes to this section:

```css
        .dropdownme {
  position: relative !important;
  display: inline-block !important;
}

.dropdownme-content {
  display: none !important;
  position: absolute !important;
  background-color: #f1f1f1 !important;
  min-width: 160px !important;
    height:500px !important;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2) !important;
  z-index: 9999999 !important;
}

.dropdownme-content a {
  color: black !important;
  padding: 12px 16px !important;
  text-decoration: none !important;
  display: block !important;
}

.dropdownme-content a:hover {background-color: #ddd !important;}

.dropdownme:hover .dropdownme-content {display: block !important;}

.dropdownme:hover .dropbtnme {background-color: #3e8e41 !important;}
```

```html
<div class="ltx-footer-social" id="naari" style="margin-top:10%; ">
<div class="container">
<div class="row ">


<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-6 dropdownme">
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-6 dropdownme">
<a href="#" target="_blank" class="item dropbtnme" data-mh="ltx-social-footer" style="height: 98px;">
<span class="icon fa fa-map-marker"></span>
<span class="header">Wanna Reach Us?</span></div>
 <div class="dropdownme-content">
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
  </div>
</div>

</div>
</div>
</div>
```

when i did the section outside of the website, in aplain page, its working fine, but when added to the website the dropdown function not working, can anyone please help, thans in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

`.vc_section` Class are overflow hidden. That's why your Dropdown not showing.If you fixed this class then your problem will be solve.

Answer (score 1):

The style on the website is not the same as you posted here. The `.dropdownme-content` definition is

```css
.dropdownme-content {
    display: block !important;
    position: absolute !important;
    background-color: #f1f1f1 !important;
    min-width: 160px !important;
    height: 500px !important;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgb(0 0 0 / 20%) !important;
    z-index: 9999999 !important;
}
```

So it's set to `display: block` already by default. Here, you posted that it is `display: none !important`. When removing the `display: block` the hover works for me.

Also, reduce the use of `important`. Good css shouldn't really need that and it will cause you a lot of problems one day or it might actually be the reason it's failing already.

Comment: sorry bro, in website i just did that to check if its displaying, i have changed it to none again, still not working, can u check

Comment: i resized the browser window and checked, its displaying, i think its hiding behind that black section, can u please help me resolve it bro